# Postgres AES encryption with pgcrypto encrypt for text of length >15 characters is not compatible with other platforms

Tags: postgresql, encryption, postgresql-12, pgcrypto

I am in a need of joining 2 tables with stringed identifiers, the key in first table is encrypted with AES ECB and the one in the second table is a raw form of that field in first table.

I am trying to achieve this by doing something like

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

select * from table1 
inner join table2 on 
( table2.rawid = convert_from(decrypt(decode(table2.encid,'BASE64'),'passwordshouldbe','AES'), 'UTF-8'));
```

This should work and it does, until the encrypted text of length > 15. Take for example:

1. `select encode(encrypt(cast('0123456789101112' as bytea),cast('passwordshouldbe' as bytea),'aes'),'BASE64');`

   (length=15)  produces  `pqWvs6RxsAqPRVUK7VFy5w==`

and

2. `select encode(encrypt(cast('0123456789101112' as bytea),cast('passwordshouldbe' as bytea),'aes'),'BASE64');`

   (length = 16) produces `+p3iTMN7zmb0wh1lk2Wk+Hbfj6WbqP1ECgtPci4nbW8=`

My java code produces the encryption as `pqWvs6RxsAqPRVUK7VFy5w==` and `+p3iTMN7zmb0wh1lk2Wk+I64/ZdIsIaXiPkdDpkCzgY=` respectively for each of the cases.

The encrypted form of the string with `length<15` is same in both cases but not for the ones above 15.

My problem is that I cant use the query I wrote for joining the tables, since trying to decrypt the values generated by java code, with encrypt in pgcrypto gives me error as

`SQL Error [22021]: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x90`

I can decrypt the Java code generated encryted string with other platforms as well

eg https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption  here

but I can only decrypt the 'pgcrypto encrypt' generated encrypted string(for data > 15 in length) from the postgresql only.

Can anyone guide me somewhere here regarding what pgcrypto is doing for encrypting longer texts than length 15.

If it is of any help, I am including the java code I used for encryption of the data.

```
public class Utilities {

private static final String ALGO = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[]{0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x62, 0x65};
//passwordshouldbe

public static String encrypt(String data) {
    try {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encVal);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         logger.error(ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) {
    try {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        return new String(decValue);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         logger.error(ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

private static Key generateKey() {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    return key;
}
```

}

Comment: You don't show what your `ALGO` variable contains; make sure that your AES parameters match on both sides, specifically the mode (CBC or ECB) and padding. The online tool you link to correctly decrypts the pgcrypto-encrypted string when the CBC mode is chosen.

Comment: Thank you @mustaccio . As you pointed out, pgcrypto was using CBC, to encrypt as a default. This is what I was missing the whole time,assuming it to be ECB. Hence , I just had to add AES-ECB to my encrypt/decrypt to make it work. eg select encode(encrypt(cast('01234567891011121314151617181920' as bytea),cast('passwordshouldbe' as bytea),'AES-ECB'),'BASE64');